# I am making a python tkinter project, but getting a error while removing all the lables from a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the code I am using:

```
# this function will be called when the user presses the jarvis button
def pressed():
    w = take_command()

    if w is None:
        pass
    elif w == "":
        pass
    else:
        main(w)
    frame_height = frame_coment.winfo_height()
    if int(frame_height) > 400:
        # from "stack overflow" code by Tom slick and minion jim...
        for widget in frame_coment.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        frame_coment.winfo_height = 0
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
 return self.func(*args)
 File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Jarvis/Jarvis.py", line 614, in pressed
 frame_height = frame_coment.winfo_height()
  TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

How can I fix this error? (Please post the code, if possible)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the last line of the function. `frame_coment.winfo_height = 0` changes `frame_coment.winfo_height`, which was a method earlier, to an integer.

So, here is how it goes:

1. The first time `pressed` is called, `frame_coment.winfo_height` **method** gets called. Then, `frame_coment.winfo_height` is assigned the **integer** value `0`.
2. The second time `pressed` is called, it attempts to call `frame_coment.winfo_height` (which is now an integer) and hence an error is raised since an `int` is not callable. Same for every subsequent call to `pressed`.

You will need to change that last line. Don't assign to `frame_coment.winfo_height`, use some other global variable instead. Somewhat like this:

```
global_variable = None  # could be any value

def pressed():
    global global_variable
    # your code
    global_variable = 0  # remove the last line and place this
```